# Will Kubuntu no longer being a funded derivative affect it's official derivative status?

Tags: kubuntu, derivatives

It's a really simple question.  I was just wondering since it has far reaching implications for the site, and it is a substantial change to the ecosystem.

Comment: Since [the status of what derivatives are official](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) is a general Ubuntu matter (and not specific to, nor determined by, the Ask Ubuntu sub-community), this question should probably be migrated to main. (Most of the question, and all of the answer, are AU-nonspecific.)

Comment: I find hbdgaf comments related to LTS for other Ubuntu flavors very good. Trying to look for a source that says if any of the Ubuntu flavors has LTS supports is very hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What funding are you talking about. If it is about Canonical (Which was a year ago) then please [read this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/kubuntu-announces-new-funding-partner)

At the current state, the development cycle will continue as normal and will meet the deadline as it has always done. You can see all development [release dates in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu)

For what it matters, Kubuntu (KDE) for me is my second best distro and Ubuntu flavor.

Comment: I was talking about the year ago thing.  I was considering the change in the context of LTS releases, where a year is really not a valid unit of measurement for the type of issue to which I was referring.  Thanks for the info and accept.

Comment: @hbdgaf Lubuntu doesn't have LTS releases anymore and they're still supported..

Comment: @Seth I don't think Lubuntu ever had LTS releases. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_10.04), Lubuntu started with 10.04, and Lubuntu 10.04 was non-LTS (while "vanilla" Ubuntu was LTS.) If I'm not mistaken, this further supports your main point--Lubuntu and Kubuntu don't have LTS releases, but [are definitely considered official](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives).